# Not getting key code for alt key flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, keyboard-events, alt-key

I am having some trouble in getting key code for alt key. Can Anyone help in it.
I am sharing for source code the way I am trying to do it.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(e:KeyboardEvent){
  trace("Key== "+e.keyCode); 
  txt.text=""+e.keyCode;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no key code for alt key. Instead, your should use [KeyboardEvent#altKey](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#altKey) getter, to check is alt key down or not.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(e:KeyboardEvent){
    if (e.altKey)
    {
        trace("Alt key is down");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this one as well. But it is working with browser only. I want to get ALT key in .swf file, without any browser. I am gonna publish flash.exe file.